# Long-lasting command in crontab

Tags: script, crontab

I want to put execution of my script in crontab every 1 hour. I wrote script that record stream using streamripper. Duration of each stream will be 7 minutes. Is it safe to put this in crontab? Maybe add ampersand in the end of path to command so script will be executed in background? Is crontab waiting for end of script execution?

Answer (score 1):

If the script only runs for 7 minutes and you're running it every hour, you should not have an issue putting it in cron.  Cron will wait for it, but that's not going to prevent cron from running anything else.